# how to virtualize config file

Tags: php, virtualization, config, interception

I have a PHP script that is encrypted with Ion Cube. Since I don't want to violate the license, I can't modify anything in the script.
The script makes calls to an XML based config file.
I want to create a database to store the config data and then feed it to the encrypted script based on the referer URL that made the request.
Basically, I want to "virtualize" the config XML file so I can feed the encrypted script the data I want based on the referer URL.

Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly do you interact with the script? Do you pass the config file name, or it is fixed within the script? Provide some basic code.

Comment: Can you configure the path of the XML file? If yes, you might be able to create your own file protocol that fetches the data from the database

Answer (score 0):

You can use LD_PRELOAD and a custom library to override the php interpreter's file open of the config file and so switch it to open a different config file on demand.